# Filter the dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down which lists several  countries and I want to display only a few countries depending on some conditions.

jquery is as below:

```
function form_onLoad() {

    var countries = "";
    if(document.forms[0].countries_new) {
        countries = document.forms[0].countries_new.value;
    }      

}
```

Dropdown :

```
 <select name="country" size="1">
    <option value=""></option>    
    <option value="1" >Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2" >Albania</option>
    <option value="3" >Algeria</option>
    <option value="4" >Andorra</option>
    <option value="5" >Angola</option>
    <option value="6" >Antigua & Deps</option>
    <option value="7" >Argentina</option>
    <option value="8" >Armenia</option>
    <option value="9" >Australia</option>
    <option value="10" >Austria</option>
    <option value="11" >Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="12" >Bahamas</option>
</select>
```

Inside the jquery, I want to replace the existing dropdown(above) which has all countries with the countries variable which has only a few options.

Comment: not clear what you want???

Comment: The existing dropdown has 12 countries. In jquery I am getting only few countries, maybe just 2 or 3 in document.forms[0].countries_new

Comment: start from data and generate the options... that way you can can filter the data based on your criteria.. e.g. `var data = [{name:'Afghanistan', value: 1}, {name:'Albania', value: 2}, ...] `

Comment: countries.value will give me only a few option values, say 1, 2. So I have to  display only Afghanistan and Albania.

Comment: I need the jquery code to filter

Comment: You should update the question with exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery library to achieve it

```
$('select[name="country"]').find('option').each(function(){
      if($(this).text()=='Armenia' || $(this).attr('value')=='12'){

          $(this).remove(); //It will remove Armenia and Bahamas
    }

 });
```

Comment: I could use this if I knew what I need to compare in the || clause. It is dynamic. As I mentioned above, Countries_new variable comes from java code which has the option values, say countries_new = 2, then only Albania is dispalyed

Comment: just to rephrase my question: Is there a way to remove options from a drop down by comparing it to a variable. Say countries = 2, so only keep 2, and remove the rest by comparing it to the countries variable.

Comment: If Countries_new variable comes from java code (not java script) you can echo that variable using scrip-let in jsp e.g.   in javascript code if($(this).text()=='<%=java_country_variable %>'){ // do your stuff here  }

Comment: Thanks Vicky! I used your approach and this piece of code worked for me:         $('select[name="country"]').find('option').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != countries ){
                $(this).remove(); 
          }

       });